# trying to use curl to download a series of files

Tags: curl, wget

I'm trying to use curl to download a seried of files in the following format:

> http://example.com/001.jpg
>
> ..
>
> http://example.com/999.jpg

So I used this command:

> time curl
>   "http://example.com/[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg"
>   -o "#1#2#3.gif"

But some of the files don't exist, and that command will create the files on my end but really it will just contain the error page.

I need a way for curl to check if it exists on the remote server before downloading it.

I know wget can do it, but wget seems to take about 5 times longer to run. The command I used to try it in wget is this:

> time wget
>   http://example.com/{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -f/--fail option:

> (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed attempts. In normal cases when a HTTP server fails to deliver a document, it returns an HTML document stating so (which often also describes why and more). This flag will prevent curl from outputting that and return error 22.
>
> This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where non-successful response codes will slip through, especially when authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).

Comment: hmm that works although it does give me an output (to the screen) when there's a 404... I don't suppose there's a way to get rid of that too so I will only see something on the screen when it works?

Comment: Well, you can stop all output with --silent option. Or just redirect errors using --stderr=filename_or_devnull, another way: "curl ... 2> filename_or_devnull" (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bash]+stderr)